# Which React TypeScript version to use in development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have an existing TypeScript React project that was created before Hooks existed in React, and I'm trying to rewrite all the classes using Hooks.

Thus in my `package.json` `"devDependencies"`, I changed the version of `typescript` react from `7.0.6` to `@types/react-redux": "7.1.16"`.  I would've imagined that I would want the exact same version of react in `"dependencies"`, but it seems there is no `7.1.16` for `react-redux`, only `7.1` and `7.2`.  I chose `7.2` and it seems to work.

More broadly, I was wondering how I can be sure I won't get versioning issues if I'm using different versions of `"react-redux"` between the development and production dependencies?

I was also wondering if I need to use `"@types/react-redux"` in both `"devDependencies"` and `"dependencies"` as opposed to just `"react-redux"`?

Answer (score 1):

It is very common that `@types` packages don't have the same version as the corresponding original package. Just use the latest version of both and you are usually good, since `@types` packages contain only type definitions and no runtime code.

Since you are probably building & bundling the result anyways, it doesn't really matter if something is a dependency or devDependency, that distinction is primarily an organizational one without any real life consequences.

Update:

There are two different scenarios here where devDependencies play a role:

- you write a library. In that case, for the person installing said library, only `dependencies` will be installed and for the person that checks out your source and runs `npm install`, both will be.
- you have an environment to run your code and install with `npm install --production`. In that case, `devDependencies` will not be installed.

Since you are building a react application though, it's very likely that you ever only run `npm install` - and that installs both dependencies and devDependencies.
Since in that case both are installed in the same folder on your harddrive, from that point it's indistinguishable which is which, so `npm start` and `npm run dev` will just use the packages that are currently installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you elaborate on why it doesn't matter if something is a ``dependency`` vs. ``devDependency``?  It's true that I'm building and bundling my code as a webpack.  I assumed that I would when using ``npm start`` it would run the code using the ``dependencies`` instead of the ``devDependencies``.

Comment: Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[phry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2075944/phry)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65897237/6309) starts with:

> It is very common that `@types` packages don't have the same version as the corresponding original package.

It does not have to be: if your project is on GitHub, you can use the [Dependabot service](https://github.com/dependabot).

From May 2022:

> ### [Dependabot keeps `@types` dependencies in sync with updated packages](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-10-dependabot-keeps-types-dependencies-in-sync-with-updated-packages/)
>
> Dependabot will now update `@types` dependencies alongside their corresponding packages in TypeScript projects.
>
> Before this change, users would see separate pull requests for a package and its corresponding `@types` package.
> This could lead to packages and type definitions getting out of sync with one another, and require manual intervention.
>
> For example, if a project had dependencies on both `jquery` and `@types/jquery`, and a vulnerability triggered Dependabot to update `jquery` from 3.4.1 to 3.5.0, the package `@types/jquery` would remain at its original 3.4.x version.
>
> Now, Dependabot can help TypeScript users keep their dependencies and `@types` packages up-to-date and in sync.
>
> When triggered to create an update, Dependabot will check if that package has a corresponding `@types` package.
>
> - If so, Dependabot will update *both* the package and the corresponding `@types` package in a single PR.
> - Or, if the `@types` package is no longer needed, that dependency will be removed instead.
>
> The feature is automatically enabled on repositories containing `@types` packages in the project's `devDependencies` as listed in `package.json`.
> You can disable this behavior by setting the ignore field in your `dependabot.yml` file to `@types/*`.

If you are building a react application, with `npm install` installing both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`, that should help.